# What fancyness can I write to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, list-questions

I'm really interested in getting answer(s) to this question ([What editors are able to correcly display an empty file, i.e. a file with not even one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799669/what-editors-are-able-to-correcly-display-an-empty-file-i-e-a-file-with-not-ev)) that has been closed.

Any ideas how I can rephrase it to make it open again and discourage others to close it again?

Should it maybe be a community wiki?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info

Comment: [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Are there any editors that cannot open an empty file, (and why would it matter)?

Comment: I quote: *"So I would like to collect a list of those editors/diff&merge that can or cannot show an empty file correctly."* I would like to collect you say - okay. Well. Get to it then. If you want something, you have to break a sweat.

Answer (score 22):

You can't change that question into one that  would be re-opened. You are asking us to find software for you. This is explicitly one of the reasons that makes a question off-topic for Stack Overflow. It should not be a community Wiki either. It might be a valid question in another Stack Exchange site and might be of interest to their community, but not for Stack Overflow.

As noted in the comments read [this information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/list-questions/info).

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on a community which might me more appropriate for such a question?

Comment: Software Recommendations Stack Exchange would be the only community where a question requesting a software recommendation, would be within scope. However, the question must meet the minimum requirements of that community, questions seeking a broad software recommendation would still be out of scope.